# Catching C++ exceptions from python while building quickfix 1.13.3

Tags: c++, python, unit-testing, exception, quickfix

I'm building Quickfix 1.13.3 on Linux Fedora. The python unit tests are failing. The test passes erroneous FIX messages to python, and python is supposed to catch the errors, and throw the appropriate exception. Whats' happening, is that the c++ layer is catching the error, throwing a c++ exception, and the test fails with a c++ core dump. I'm assuming that python is supposed to be catching these exceptions, but it isn't

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Did you find answer for this Lucio?